# y_true and y_pred have different number of output (10!=1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit learn wrapper KerasClassifier for hyperparameters tuning for my LSTM model using RandomizedSearchCV. Below is a summary of what I am doing:
1. xtrain has the shape [355,5,10] and ytrain has the shape[355,10], There are 355 training samples and 10 features and labels.
2. First I create the model using build_lstm_model function
3. Define KerasClassifier
4. Specify parameters that to be sued for fitting to determine the scoring
5. Specify parameters to be searched using RandomizedSearchCV
5. fit the model

I am using 'neg_mean_squared_error' as the scoring metrics. When I run the code I get an error "y_true and y_pred have different number of output (10!=1)"

I found that, if I do not specify any scoring metrics, then it works fine. But, I want to use neg_mean_squared_error, since its a regression problem.

```py
# keras model
def build_lstm_model(n_blocks=6, n_cells=40, lr=0.001, lookback=lookback, n=n):
    model = Sequential()

    for i in range(n_blocks-1):
        model.add(LSTM(n_cells, input_shape=(lookback, n), return_sequences=True, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='uniform'))

    model.add(LSTM(n_cells, input_shape=(lookback, n), activation='tanh', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(n))

    adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

# pass in fixed parameters n_input and n_class
model_lstm = KerasClassifier(
    build_fn = build_lstm_model,
    lookback = lookback, n = n)

# specify other extra parameters pass to the .fit
# number of epochs is set to a large number
keras_fit_params = {   
    'epochs': 10,
    'batch_size': 16,
    'validation_data': (xvalid, yvalid),
    'verbose': 0
}

# random search parameters 
# specify the options and store them inside the dictionary
# batch size and training method can also be hyperparameters, but it is fixed
n_blocks_params = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
n_cells_params = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
lr_params = [0.001, 0.0001]

keras_param_options = {
    'n_blocks': n_blocks_params,
    'n_cells': n_cells_params,  
    'lr': lr_params
}

# `verbose` 2 will print the class info for every cross-validation, kind of too much
rs_lstm = GridSearchCV( 
    model_lstm, 
    param_distributions = keras_param_options,
    #fit_params = keras_fit_params,
    scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error',
    n_iter = 3, 
    cv = 5,
    n_jobs = -1
    #verbose = 0
)

rs_lstm.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
```

Is there a way I can use mean_squared_error as the metrics in RandomizedSearchCV?

Comment: What is the value of "n" in your code?

Comment: n = 10 in my code.

Comment: I think the error is due to the different shape of y_true and y_pred while using mean_squired_error metric. I created a custom metric function as below. I found that the y_true has the (71, ) and y_pred has (71,10) shape. 71 corresponds to give fold (355/5 = 71). I am not able to figure out why is y_true has (71,) shape. Because y_train has the shape [355,10]. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was using KerasClassifier. I didn't know that there is another wrapper KerasRegressor in SKlearn. When I use KerasRegressor, I can use regression related metrics for finding a good model. Thank you.